# Why does inverse quadratic interpolation converge quicker than inverse linear interpolation

Tags: analysis, numerical-methods, roots, interpolation, lagrange-interpolation

I have used linear inverse interpolation and quadratic inverse interpolation to estimate the root of a function. I found that my linear interpolation procedure required 9 iterations to achieve convergence of the root. My quadratic interpolation required just 2 iterations to converge to the root. Is it a general rule that the higher the order of the interpolatory polynomial, the quicker the convergence? If so, why?

Comment: Usually, the convergence rate is better , if the degree of the convergence is higher. Newton's method has usually degree $2$ and the iteration $x_n=x_{n-1}+\sin(x_{n-1})$ with $x_0=3$ converges to $\pi$ cubic , that is with degree $3$.

Comment: Basically, the number of correct digits multiplies with the degree in each step (from some point on), hence the convergence is faster if the degree is higher.

Comment: "My quadratic interpolation required just 2 iterations to converge to the root." That sounds suspiciously fast, as if you are either starting ridiculously close to the root (relative to your termination condition) or the function is basically an inverse quadratic.